# Linear Algebra- Describe all solutions of ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit lost with this current problem:

Let A= \begin{bmatrix}1&-2&3&4\\3&-6&9&12\end{bmatrix}
Describe all solutions of Ax=0

The solution is set up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnzEH.png).

I'm at a total loss of how to solve it. I know it ends up being A= [1 -2 3 4] and I solve for x2, x3, and x4. I'm apparently inputting it wrong or I'm doing it wrong altogether. Can someone show me the steps of how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $x = [x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]^T$. Then,the following equation is true if $Ax=0$:
$$
x_1-2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=0
$$
(The other equation is the same as this multiplied by $3$)

Now, simplify this, to $x_1 = 2x_2-3x_3-4x_4$. Hence, we can rewrite the solution as : $(2x_2-3x_3-4x_4,x_2,x_3,x_4)$.

Now it is easy to see that if $X$ is a solution of $AX=0$, then:
$$
X = x_2\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\0 \\0\end{bmatrix} + x_3\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0\\1 \\0\end{bmatrix} + x_4\begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 0 \\0 \\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

On adding component wise, this gives:
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_2-3x_3-4x_4 \\ x_2 \\x_3 \\x_4\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which satisfies the equation $AX=0$.